# "return count(n) as count" returns zero rows when count(n) = 0

Tags: neo4j

With an empty database, `match (n) return count(n);` returns one row with the value 0, as expected, but `match (n) return count(n) as count;` returns zero rows, as does `match (n) return count(n),1;`. Is there some way to make `return` treat `count(n)` the same with or without an alias or additional columns in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "as expected", but I'm not so sure what's to be expected. None of the queries match anything. When you then return an aggregate function, it's not so much that the aggregate function counts to 0 as that it doesn't count at all. There are no matches, so there is no occasion to do the count. The fact that it returns 0 when the return clause consists only of an 'unreachable' aggregation suggests that it is returning a default value. But as soon as you are getting after actual values–aggregations, literals or otherwise–the result will be conditional on there actually being some match in the database. Since there are no matches, it won't return any values, not even the default count 0. Consider

```
MATCH (a)
RETURN "a"
```

If there are no matches, would you expect "a" to be returned? If not, then with

```
MATCH (a) 
RETURN COUNT(a), "a"
```

if you want `COUNT(a)` to be 0 when there are no matches for (a), then you have to return "a". But that would be confusing, no?

By making the match pattern optional you can let the query 'reach' the count and literal. To return `0, a`

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)
RETURN COUNT(a), "a"
```

By the way, your second query returns one row with value 0 for me, same as the first query.